# MySQL information_schema.statistics table with 0 cardinality

Tags: mysql, information-schema, cardinality

My DB schema of MySql 8.0.19 has a table with indexes on 3 columns of it. Table has around 40,000 rows. Distinct value of those 3 columns are 19k, 5k, 10. Primary key is auto generated id. I was expecting cardinality value of information_schema.statistics for this table to be around these values. But to my wonder, it is set to 0 for all 4 columns.

I debugged to this point as query involving join to this table is taking a lot of time. I strongly doubt that the index is either corrupt or not getting built. It is innodb table.

I have already tried deleting all the data from the table and reinserting but still query is taking time and cardinality is 0.

As compared to other tables, check table table_name command also takes significantly longer for this table.

Can someone give some pointer why indexes are not getting built and cardinality remains 0?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does explain say about the index use of your query?

Comment: Possible Keys has the indexed columns mentioned. Key does not have indexed columns. Extra has "Using where"

Comment: Meanwhile I dropped the table and created it again and populated with same data and this time cardinality is shown correctly and query is 200 times faster. Not sure what caused this cardinality to become 0. Was it a corrupt index?